# Fallout4: Reunions mission bug

Tags: fallout-4

This is a fairly odd and I do not know how to fix this, but during the Reunions mission where you have to follow Dogmeat, Dogmeat disappeared sometime after passing a law enforcement robot that was killed by Kellogg. This is extremely unusual and I cannot find any answer to this question. It could be a possibility that dogmeat stopped for me to look for clues and I just passed him, or he is at the place we were going already.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I am playing on the Xbox One version of the game

Comment: As a workaround you might be able to use the console to teleport him back to you if you are on PC.

Comment: On PC, you can get into fort hagen and TCL through a boarded up door to trigger kellog's dialog and start the quest. Kill him, leave the fort, the BOS should appear like normal. On Xbox, keep searching for Dogmeat and hope, or reload a prior save.

Answer (score 2):

If your current quest objective is to follow dogmeat, and you have the quest marked in your Pip-Boy, then you should have a quest marker leading to him. If that objective is complete, then you simply need to enter Kellog's base to continue. If it's not complete, but there's no marker, here are some things you can try:

**Finding Dogmeat**

I don't recall any law enforcement robots on the trail, but there is an assaultron shortly after passing [Forest Grove Marsh](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forest_Grove_marsh). There is a cigar on the box the assaultron's wreck is lying upon, which is the clue here. You're supposed to grab it and show it to Dogmeat. If you did this, then he would have started toward the next clue. It doesn't seem like you always need to actually kneel down and show him the clue. Sometimes he just takes off.

If this is where you are, then the next clue is a bloody rag on a chain link fence up the hill toward the [Greater Mass Blood Clinic](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_Mass_blood_clinic). After the robot, continue up the road a ways until you get to the intersection. Take a right, then veer left up the hill.

The rag is next to a break in the fence that you can walk through. Maybe Dogmeat is over there. That's the last clue before Kellog's base

> at Fort Hagen.

**Entering the Base**

If you can't find Dogmeat, that might be okay. I've previously ditched Dogmeat and ran ahead to enter the base, and everything went fine. I can't recall if that was definitely before the last bloody rag, though.

To do this, you need to enter

> Fort Hagen, and get to the basement via the elevator after the ceiling turret. This elevator will be inaccessible before a quest trigger in Reunions, so if it doesn't work when you get there then you've missed a quest trigger and have a problem.

To get inside, you can either take the roof entrance or go in through the basement.

> The roof entrance of Fort Hagen is guarded by a bunch of turrets. You can completely ignore and avoid these by using the door in the Parking Garage next door. Go down the stairs. You'll find a hideout room with a dead person and some supplies. Leave the room toward the main part of the garage, and you should find a blue door on the same floor.

Go in, and it should complete the "Follow Dogmeat" objective.

**Load and Try Again**

If you find that none of this works, then you'll likely need to load a save from before the robot.

If you're playing a Bethesda game and you don't have a trail of saves to go back to, then you're doing it wrong. Anytime you do something you don't want to do again, save.

Answer (score 0):

At some point he just buggers off and you don’t need him anymore. (I think my Dogmeat went to Sanctuary Hills to chill in a random doghouse there.)

IF you *do* need Dogmeat for your current objective, you should be able to use the Objectives/Maps features of your Pip-boy to track him down.

Comment: I have checked all my settlements and looked at the map, I cannot find him, so unless he is in a random doghouse in the middle of nowhere, it is safe to assume that the game has bugged out and despawned him

Comment: Maybe. But he can be really hard to find. I almost gave up, myself, but there he was in Sanctuary Hills.

Comment: Note that Sanctuary Hills has multiple doghouses. You should find and delete all but one of them to make him easier to find. (It still won't guarantee that he will be waiting at a doghouse.)

Comment: You can also try the Red Rocket Truck Stop where you first found him. When I lost him, that's where he was.

Comment: Yep, that’s a good tip, too. Man, I wish Bethesda made it easy to find companions and other characters in Fallout! Like that crazy wandering guy with the rare armor, you know?